# CSS file not found. Django project

Tags: html, css, django

my django project wont find my css file. Spelling is correct, path is correct, lower and upper cases are correct, its linked in the head part. ive been searching for 2 hours now.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/Templates/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    -->
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>       
        .form-control{
          width: 50%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container" id="thisone">

    <h3 class="">BlaBlaBla!</h3>
    <h5>{{ message }}</h5>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

is this a stupid fail of mine?

Greetings

Comment: Check your directory traversal, `../` also it isnt advised to use that it is better to use hard links

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also tried without ../ and copied the exact link. still didnt work.

Comment: Are you sure you need `src` in the url?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check Your path again,
If it's correct
Follow the Guidelines to Include CSS in Django Project

Static files are intended to wrap CSS files and your images, Django automatically identifies this file.

1. Create `static` folder in your `app` folder, same directory as of migrations and template folder
2. Create `css` Folder and insert it into static Folder
3. Now put your `styles.css` into `css` folder
4. Now in your HTML File where you want to include CSS, add `{% load static %}` On the top of HTML File and **Your Path should be like this** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">` in HTML file.
5. Then Make Change To Your settings.py in projectfoldername with-

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
   ]

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

Then Run this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You static file will be copied to New file created by django as assets.

If it does not reflect changes [Refer here If it does not work](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Oh fawk. Nobody mentioned the "python manage.py collectstatic" command. It worked. Thank you for your quick and solution!

Comment: Yes! sometime your css would not reflect into you project then simply run this command `python manage.py collectstatic` . It copies everything in your assest folder.

Comment: I've followed your steps exactly but when I run ```python manage.py collectstatic``` I get the following error: ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\callum\\Project1\\static'```. I have 4 folders in my "Project1" folder, my css file is located in ```Project1/app1/static/css/styles.css```

Comment: You could refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991707/12045111, if it's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official statement "Generally, the templates folder is created and kept in the sample directory where manage.py lives. This templates folder contains all the templates you will create in different **Django Apps**."

As a Django projects grow in size it's often more convenient to have all the templates in one place rather than hunting for them within multiple apps.

Just as an additional information for the accepted answer's 1."Statement"

Besides, yes you should have your static folder at App-level and it should work!.